# Optimizing a MySQL table for faster select operation

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have a MySQL table which contains Aggregate Revenue of a company for two year from it's different clients to perform analysis on Current year Revenue and future Revenue forcast, having these fields for time,

- MonthID,
- QuarterID and
- YearID

It is having month wise data, also have quarter wise (I can get that by aggregating the month, but have added row for faster select for quarter..i am showing that on a graph) and so on Year wise.

Now to reduce some data count and for optimization for faster select, I have removed MonthID, QtrID and YrID. And added a new column Frequency, that has values like

- Last Month
- 1st Qtr
- 2nd Qtr

So on, It has reduced my row counts to half, but still i don't feel it very optimized, some expert advice will be highly appreciated that what can else be done on this. My table has around a million records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Warehousing with millions of rows begs for "Summary Tables".  With them you can get significant speedup; typically 10-fold.

I would build Summary Table(s) on a per-month basis (based on your specs), then roll them up to get Qtr and Year "reports".

I have a pair of blogs that goes into more detail:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse and 
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

One million rows is somewhat small as DW applications go.  Those blogs are aimed at that size, plus much bigger DWs (10s, even 100s, of millions of rows).  (For 1 billion rows, even more techniques need to be pulled into play.)

If you have further difficulties, please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE and some tentative SELECTs.  Those would help me point out details.